# Cover a surface with disks of various size

Tags: algorithms, approximation

I'm trying to find a cover of a surface using disks of variable sizes.

In the image, I want to cover the entire blue surface. The disks can go "out" of the blue surface and into the red part, but they cannot go outside the red area. The red area is always an "expansion" of the blue area.

I'm trying to find a solution that minimizes the number of disks used. I am not looking for the perfect solution, an approximate one is fine too!

The example shows a cross, but the shape can be anything (no holes though)

If it's easier, we could also use squares instead of circles.

[image: Example]

Thank you :)

Comment: Only polygons (straight line segments), or anything, even circles?  Only convex polygons, or also convex polygons?   Can you cover it with triangles?

Comment: In any case it will be approximated by segments. 
There is no restriction on the concave/convex situation of the polygon.
I do not really understand your question about triangles. I can cover it with anything, as I have the "safe area" in red, and forms can overlap.

Comment: Circles are really bad for covering polygons, whereas [polygon triangulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon_triangulation) has good properties.

Comment: I understand that triangles would be optimal, but I cannot do that. I need to use a single shape that can be scaled, not deformed.

I understand that both minimization are in conflict, but I am not looking for an exact solution (which would be impossible as there are no cost function, as you said).
Let's say that I want to minimize only the number of disks needed (I'll append the question)